# Who has criticized the scientific field of sociology of religion as secular and Christian?

Tags: sociology

Which thinkers criticize the scientific field of sociology of religion as being secular and about Christianity?

I couldn’t find a stach exchange for sociology. So I ask here.

Comment: See [Milbank, Policing the Sublime](http://www.religion.ranepa.ru/en/node/489).

Comment: Durkheim founded sociology as an academic discipline, and really began the process in the Abrahamic world of taking non-monotheistic religious traditions intellectually seriously. What he found though, is when you open the definition wide enough for Sanatan Dharma ('Hinduism') and Confucianism, a lot of supposedly secular society has to be looked at as religious-ish. What is your motivation?